# Is it possible to receive notifications when a contact is added on the iOS and Android platforms?

Tags: android, ios, ios4, ios5

Question says it all. Looking for a way for a custom app to be able to keep track within minutes of when a contact has been added to the built in contacts database on both of these platforms. For example, if I get an email on my iPhone, and add the sender to my contacts, I'd like for the custom app to be able to know that within a minute at most.

Are there hooks for this? Naturally it would require the user authorizing the custom app to have access to this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There aren't any hooks for this in iOS.  You can access the address book, but only when your application is running.

Comment: Is it possible to keep your application running indefinitely (with the user's permission)? What about Android?

Comment: Not really.  There are narrowly-defined areas where your application can execute in the background, such as for VOIP or as a media player, but not in the general case, not if you want to be accepted into the App Store.  I'm unsure about Android.

Comment: any idea about Blackberry's OS?